# conflicting type between typedef and struct

Tags: c, types, linked-list

i have a little problem, i declared a type with typedef in my file "single_list.h", and implemented the struct for this type in "single_list.c", but i go a bunch of conflicting type, i don't understand why :

**singe_list.h**

```
typedef struct single_list_node SingleListNode;

typedef struct single_list SingleList;

COMDS_RETURN *comds_slist_init(SingleList **list, void (*destroy)(void *data),
        int (*compare)(const void *fdata, const void *sdata));  

void comds_slist_destroy(SingleList *list);

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_insert_next(SingleList *list, SingleListNode *node, void *data); 

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_remove(SingleList *list, void **data);

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_remove_next(SingleList *list, 
    SingleListNode *node, void ** data);

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_find(const SingleList *list, 
    SingleList **out, const void *data);
```

**single_list.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "error.h"
#include "single_list.h" 

struct single_list_node {
    void *data;
    struct SingleListNode_ *nextNode;
};

struct single_list {
    SingleListNode *head;
    SingleListNode *tail;
    size_t size;    
    void (*destroy)(void *data);
    int (*compare)(const void *fdata, const void *sdata);
};

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_init(SingleList **list, void (*destroy)(void *data),
        int (*compare)(const void *fdata, const void *sdata))
{   
    if((*list = malloc(sizeof *list)) == NULL)
        return COMDS_ALLOC_FAIL;


    *list->head = NULL; 
    *list->tail = NULL; 
    *list->size = 0; 
    *list->destroy = destroy; 
    *list->compare = compare;

    return COMDS_SUCESS;
} 

void comds_slist_destroy(SingleList *list) 
{

    void *data;

    if(list->destroy)
        while(list->head)
        { 
            comds_slist_remove_next(list, NULL, &data);
            list->destroy(data);
        }
    free(list);
}


COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_insert_next(SingleList *list, SingleListNode *node,
    void *data)
{

    SingleListNode *addnode = malloc(sizeof *addnode);

    if(addnode == NULL)
        return COMDS_ALLOC_FAIL;

    addnode->data = data;

    if(node == NULL) {
        addnode->nextNode = list->head;
        node = list->head = addnode; // using node for checking list tail
    }
    else {
        addnode->nextNode = node->nextNode;
        node->nextNode = addnode;
    }

    // updating list->tail if needed
    if(node == list->tail)
        list->tail = addnode;

    list->size++;

    return COMDS_SUCESS;
}

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_remove(SingleList *list, void **data) 
{
    SingleListNode *node, *prevNode = NULL;

    if(list->compare)
        for(node = list->head; node != NULL && 
            list->compare && list->compare(*data, node->data) != 0;
            prevNode = node, node = node->nextNode);
    else 
        for(node = list->head; node != NULL && 
            node->data != *data;
            prevNode = node, node = node->nextNode);

    if(node != NULL) {
        return comds_slist_remove_next(list, prevNode, data);
    }

    return COMDS_ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND;
}

COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_remove_next(SingleList *list, SingleListNode *node, void **data)
{
    SingleListNode *remNode;

    // the list still not contain any node
    if(list->size == 0 || (node && node->nextNode == NULL)) 
        return COMDS_ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND;

    if(node == NULL) {
        *data = list->head->data;
        remNode = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->nextNode;
    }
    else {
        *data = node->nextNode->data;
        remNode = node->nextNode;

        node->nextNode = node->nextNode->nextNode;
    }

    if(remNode == list->tail)
        list->tail = node;

    free(remNode);
    list->size--;

    return COMDS_SUCESS;
}

// iterate over the list node per node until finding the right node
// compare function must return 0 if the two data are the same
// if the function compare is 'NULL', a pointer comparaison is done
COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_find(const SingleList *list, SingleList **out,
    const void *data) 
{   

    if(list->size == 0) 
        return COMDS_ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND;

    SingleListNode *node = list->head;

    if(list->compare)
        while(node != NULL && list->compare(node->data, data) != 0)
            node = node->nextNode;
    else 
        while(node != NULL && node->data != data)
            node = node->nextNode;

    *out = node;
    return COMDS_SUCESS;
}
```

**errors**

```
single_list.c:19:14: error: conflicting types for ‘comds_slist_init’
In file included from single_list.c:4:0:
single_list.h:23:15: note: previous declaration of ‘comds_slist_init’ was here
single_list.c: In function ‘comds_slist_init’:
single_list.c:26:7: error: request for member ‘head’ in something not a structure or union
single_list.c:27:7: error: request for member ‘tail’ in something not a structure or union
single_list.c:28:7: error: request for member ‘size’ in something not a structure or union
single_list.c:29:7: error: request for member ‘destroy’ in something not a structure or union
single_list.c:30:7: error: request for member ‘compare’ in something not a structure or union
single_list.c: In function ‘comds_slist_insert_next’:
single_list.c:62:21: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c:67:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c: In function ‘comds_slist_remove’:
single_list.c:86:26: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c:90:26: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c: In function ‘comds_slist_remove_next’:
single_list.c:110:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c:113:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
single_list.c:114:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c:116:34: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
single_list.c: In function ‘comds_slist_find’:
single_list.c:142:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c:145:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
single_list.c:147:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Comment: I fear this code is incomplete. wher's the typedef for `SingleListNode`
?

Comment: You've got a problem with type definitions, publish **ALL** the relevant structs / typedefs, and **ONLY** the relevant structs / typedefs. Publishing your entire code contributes nothing to the question at hand (let alone confuses the readers). As a side-note: get rid of those macros at the beginning, they contribute nothing to the readability of your code (well, to be more accurate, they contribute a negative factor).

Comment: Edit your question and post the error messages *exactly* as they are.

Comment: updated, sorry it was a copy/paste error

Comment: Another error is `struct SingleListNode_`  , presumably you just meant `SingleListNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the `conflicting types` error, here's the reason:

Header:

```
COMDS_RETURN *comds_slist_init( /* args */ );
```

Source:

```
COMDS_RETURN comds_slist_init( /* args */ ) { /* def */ }
```

The return type is `COMDS_RETURN *` in one file and  `COMDS_RETURN` in the other.